# socket.io ssl connection in node.js with express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl, socket.io

I am quite confused about setting up a secure ssl connection on node.js and the bindings created with the socket.io.
It is giving big headaches, as it is constantly refusing to work, and the result in browsers tested are:

> GET https://webrtc.romlex.info/socket.io/1/?t=1405428623632 404 (Not Found) socket error

My serverside code:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/video-phone/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/video-phone/cert.pem')
};
```

actually i am only initializing express

```
var app = express();
```

should i create server when initializing express, and pass options?

```
var app = express.createServer(options);
```

actually i am creating the https server with the options listening on secured port

```
var server = require('https').createServer(options,app).listen(443);
```

which way should i initialize socket.io connection?
Actually i am listening on server with options

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,options);
```

Should i listen on server only?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Or should i listen on the secure port and options?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(443,options);
```

Quite a bit confused, please help!

i am using xhr-polling over websockets

```
io.set('transports', [
    //'websocket',
    'xhr-polling',
    'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

the serverside code:
[serverside socket.io with ssl](https://gist.github.com/zludany/b35e0bad19381b39dec7)

clientside code:

should i add secure param or not?

```
io.connect("https://webrtc.romlex.info", {secure: true});
```

Sorry for the questions, i'm quite a newbie on node.js, especially, when ssl connection comes to scene.
Thanks for your suggestions!